# Continuous-states hidden Markov chain

Tags: references, continuous-data, hidden-markov-model

How to deal with HMC that has continuous states?

Any papers, links, materials that explain the solution?

Comment: Particle filters and sequential Monte Carlo are perfectly equipped for dealing with hidden Markov chains with continuous state spaces. See e.g. <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441923195/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=217145&creative=399373&creativeASIN=1441923195">Inference in Hidden Markov Chains</a> by Cappé, Moulines and Rydén.

Comment: Most obvious suggestion is to read on state space models, but to get a good answer it might be a good idea to be a little more specific. What do you mean by "deal with", and "the solution" of what? State estimation, parameter estimation, prediction, or do you have an application in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The Kalman filter is a very simple version of a hidden markov chain in which the states are described as normal distributions. There are several tutorials and introductory texts dealing with kalman filters (easily found through google).

If this is too simplistic, there are several extensions (Extended Kalman Filter, switching Markov models, etc.). It really depends on the specific problem in which you are interested in applying them.